# Custom Login page in Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I have a task at work, It is to implement the login page inside the Docusaurus.
I am trying to customizing the `index.js` by adding some `HelloWorld`. Including  `login.js` which has actual Docusaurus Index page

```
const Index = require('./login.js');

const React = require('react');
class Button extends React.Component {
render() {
   return ("helloworld");}
} 
module.exports = Button;
```

But Error thrown is:
`Error: Cannot find module './login.js'`

Is it possible to call the class from another `js` page in Docusaurus?

Answer (score 8):

Docusaurus maintainer here! Yes, it should be possible as the current module system is CommonJS. You have to put that component in the same directory as `index.js`. Link me to a repository if possible and I can help you take a look.

On a side note, it doesn't make much sense to build a login form for Docusaurus as Docusaurus generates a static site that loses state across page navigations unless you persist them in cookies or `localStorage`. It'd be quite troublesome to do so. Maybe you could explain what you're trying to build here and I can recommend you better alternatives.

Comment: I was thinking on using this but for the internal company process, so I want to know a method to make it only available to some people...

Comment: I'm trying to do the same: I have a pre existing Python API which is going to set a cookie. The static Docusaurus site could render react components differently (or redirect to /login directly) if they click on a login protected page, and no cookie is set. Right?

Is there a better standard practice in docusaurus in 2022?

Answer (score 4):

I found a way to work this out, even though there is no official documentation on this matter. I used the Docusaurus Swizzle to intervene in the Root component so that I can use Firebase Authentication (I think that you can use Auth0 or any custom logic in replacement).

I wrote a detailed blog on this so that I hope it can help others, you can see it here: https://medium.com/@thomasdevshare/docusaurus-authentication-with-firebase-c824da24bc51

There is also full example source code in the article, you can clone it.

Comment: I'm curious if this is a secure method. I'm pretty new to SSR and still confused about some things. Firebase Auth works in the browser. So, what it prevents is *rendering* for unauthorized users. But I'm not sure how it prevents sending private HTML files to unauthorized users. Could you explain how your code is safe in terms of SSR?

Answer (score 1):

First of all. What does "login.js" look like? It is an exported module with a well defined (default) namespace?

Secondly, you shouldn't add the file extension to an import. It's "require('./login')" not "require('./login.js')".